# Error contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

This is my first Table : Tours

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tours] (

[Id]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TourId]          INT            NOT NULL,
[TCountry]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[TName]           NVARCHAR (100) NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_Tours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TourId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Tours_ToTourDates] FOREIGN KEY ([TourId]) REFERENCES [TourDates]([TourId]));
```

and this is the next, Table:TourDates

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TourDates] (

[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TourId]        INT            NOT NULL,
[TourStartDate] DATETIME       NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_TourDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

for first table I have this Error :

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[TourDates]' contains no
> primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in
> the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it
> should be persisted.

How can one define a Candidate key for `TourId` column in `TourDates` Table??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should be doing something else than you are doing right now.
`Tours` table seems to hold every tour which should be in 1:N relationship with `TourDates` provided that I understand it correctly.

Thus, your FOREIGN KEY constraint should actually be declared on `TourDates`, not `Tours` table.

---

As to your issue (which I believe wouldn't if you switch those relationships to what they should be in my understanding) in such cases you would normally need to create a unique index on that column.

You can't reference a column which may contain several exact same values via foreign key constraint, thus the need for some sort of a unique key.

---

**Edit after comment:**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDates]
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Tour_TourDates
   FOREIGN KEY ([TourId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tours]([TourId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: thanks for you'r care. yes exactly it's 1:N relationship with TourDates. but I need to do some how when one of Tours deleted then all tourdates of that tourId should be delete. I need On delete cascade in table tours... Is it possible in the way you explained to have on delete cascade in tourdates foreign key?